# Lessons in maths: Preposition

Tags: prepositions, word-request

> Lessons in maths, in history, in geography...Today we had two lessons in maths.

Is there any other acceptable preposition expressing the "school" meaning of a lesson? For example, OF, AT? ("Lessons of history" is gramatically correct but it means quite the other things.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prepositions which usually get used when referring to teaching a subject are:

> Today we had two lessons **in** differential equations.
>   *in a subject*
>
> Today we had two lessons **on** differential equations.
>   *on a subject*
>
> Today we had two lessons **about** differential equations.
>   *about a subject*